# What is the default time precision of DateTime?

Tags: c#, datetime, precision

I did a small winform program for data transferring in Visual Studio, and I used a method to provide the transferring time duration. After the transferring being done, the program will return a dialog window to show the time.

But here I don't know what is the time precision or the resolution of the timer, how can it be such a precision, even micro second?

```
var startTime = DateTime.Now;
this.transferdata();
var endTime = DateTime.Now;
var timeElapsed = endTime.Subtract(startTime);
```

[image]

when I saw the definition of class DateTime, there is only a precision in milisecond. can anybody tell me why there is such a high resolution timer in the visual studio 2012? Or there is related to the operating system?

Comment: Precision and accuracy of DateTime: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/04/08/precision-and-accuracy-of-datetime.aspx (_"The problem that arises with having that much precision is of course that it is very easy to assume that a given value is as accurate as it is precise. But that’s not warranted at all!"_)

Comment: 1. This has nothing to do with Visual Studio. It's the .NET Framework that is doing this, and under the covers it goes down to Windows. 2. You could use the `Stopwatch` type - it might be a little more accurate, but the level of precision around "What time is it" you seem to be expecting doesn't exist in Windows.

Comment: `DateTime` has precision down to the tick, not the millisecond. (There are 10 ticks in a *microsecond*.)

Comment: Think of it this way - just because a `DateTime` variable can store lots of decimal places, doesn't mean that the internal system clock uses all of them.  Also, don't ever use `DateTime.Now` for this, use `DateTime.UtcNow` or preferably a `Stopwatch`.

Answer (score 6):

The precision of the clock depends on the operating system. The system clock ticks a certain number of times per second, and you can only measure whole ticks.

You can test the resolution for a specific computer using code like this:

```
DateTime t1 = DateTime.Now;
DateTime t2;
while ((t2 = DateTime.Now) == t1) ;
Console.WriteLine(t2 - t1);
```

On my computer the result is `00:00:00.0156253`, which means that the system clock ticks 64 times per second.

(Note: The `DateTime` type also has ticks, but that is not the same as the system clock ticks. A `DateTime` tick is 1/10000000 second.)

To measure time more precisely, you should use the `Stopwatch` class. Its resolution also depends on the system, but is much higher than the system clock. You can get the resolution from the `Stopwatch.Frequency` property, and on my computer it returns `2143566` which is *a tad more* than 64...

Start a stopwatch before the work and stop it after, then get the elapsed time:

```
Stopwatch time = Stopwatch.StartNew();
this.transferdata();
time.Stop();
TimeSpan timeElapsed = time.Elapsed;
```

That will return the time in the resolution that the `TimeSpan` type can handle, e.g. 1/10000000 second. You can also calculate the time from the number of ticks:

```
double timeElapsed = (double)s.ElapsedTicks / (double)Stopwatch.Frequency;
```

Comment: One caution here, since Windows is not a real time operating system you risk something else suddenly hogging the CPU for a while increasing your measured number. I would run a sequence of such tests and pick the lowest number, unless a more certain way exists to get the actual tick size.

Comment: @Guffa - your "test" is not accurate, since the OS might switch away from your process while it is in the "while" loop and that time may take longer the actual resolution of DateTime.Now.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: Yes, running the test more than wise is of course wise.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch: Maybe I was unclear, but that test is of course not meant as a one-off to measure the system clock. It's a simple test that tests the system clock, but you should of course run it more than once to get a certain result.

Comment: Consider using `DateTime.UtcNow`.  `DateTime.Now` is slower because it has to do time zone conversions.  Also, if you use `DateTime.Now` and you cross a daylight saving time transition, you will get unexpected results.  :)

Comment: @MattJohnson: Use that for what? The answer says to use `Stopwatch` for timing.

Comment: In your first example code you show measuring the resolution timing with `DateTime.Now`.

Comment: @MattJohnson: That's just a simple test to find out the system clock frequency. It doesn't need better performance or protection from edge cases.

Comment: Sure, but if you measure that with `DateTime.Now`, then you're including all of the code that gets the local time zone and converts the UTC time to it.  `DateTime.UtcNow` is a system call.  `DateTime.Now` [wraps that with extra stuff](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/datetime.cs#939).

Comment: @MattJohnson: I think that you are missing the point. You are trying to optimise code that has absolutely no need to be optimised.

Comment: @Guffa so, you are trying to say that the results of your test won't change if you optimize the code by using `DateTime.UtcNow`?

Answer (score 5):

You are confusing several things.   Precision, Accuracy, Frequency, and Resolution.

You might have a variable that is accurate to a billion decimal places.  But if you can't actually measure that small of a number then that's the difference between precision and resolution.  Frequency is the number of times per second a measurement is taken, while relates to resolution.  Accuracy is how closely a given sample is to the real measurement.

So, given that DateTime has a precision much higher than the system clock, simply saying DateTime.Now will not necessarily give you an exact timestamp.  There are, however, Higher resolution timers in Windows, and the Stopwatch class uses them to measure time elapsed, so if you use this class you get a much better accuracy.

DateTime has no "default precision".  It has only one precision, and that's the Minimum and Maximum values it can store.  DateTime internally stores it's values as a single value, and this value is formatted to whatever type you want to display (seconds, minutes, days, ticks, whatever...).